# powershell command Line arguments get lost if directly running from CMD

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

**Need help**

*Example*

Working : **C:\SDK>powershell TESTPS1.ps1 a1 a2 a3**

Not Working : **C:\SDK>.\TESTPS1.ps1 a1 a2 a3**

in above examples both command runs script but 2nd command which is running script without *powershell* as prefix does not capture argument in args .

*Powershell is default app launcher for ps1 extension .*

**Script** : TESTPS1.ps1

## --------------------------------------------

write-host "Running Script "

write-host $args

write-host "Script Completed!!"

## --------------------------------------------

Comment: yes, you cant execute a powershell script from cmd ...

Comment: See here: http://forloveofsoftware.blogspot.ca/2009/04/calling-powershell-script-in-path-with.html

Comment: Running `.\afile` from cmd, will open this file in the default associated app

Answer (score 0):

.\file will open it in the default application. By default this is supposed to be notepad.exe for .ps1 files. The class mapping for .ps1 files probably has not been setup to properly pass arguments. Enabling this is a potential security risk and not enabled by default for a reason.

For how to manually do this you will need to look in to setting up a custom registry class like .ps1 %1